# Is there any way to read from the Facebook Ticker (App or Stream) using the Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ticker

I have done some research and know there is currently no way to post specifically to the Facebook ticker, but I am curious if API developers are able to get any information out of the ticker using the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For facebook application achievement tickers, you can found that from :

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/539/